# join two tables on multiple columns maintaing relation between the columns

Tags: join, multiple-columns

Tab1
Columns [F,S,E]

F1      S1      R

F1  S2  R2

F1  S3  R1

F2  S1  R2

F2  S4  R4

F1  S4  R

Tab2
Columns[F,S]

F1  S1

F1  S3

F2  S1

F2  S4

TAKE ROWS FROM TAB1 FOR ONLY IF F->S RELATION IS PRESENT IN Tab2

RESULT
Columns[F,S,E]

F1  S1  R

F1  S3  R

F2  S4  R4

Please note a simple inner join wont work here.. as there is a relation between F and S.

Using inner join results in return of a row F1 S4 R, but F1 and S4 have no relation between them.

Thanks in advance

inner join left join

Comment: Your example results don't seem to match your problem statement, the (F=F1, S=S3) relation has a value of R1 not R in your Tab1, and the relation (F=F2, S=S1) occurs in row 4 of Tab1 and row 3 of Tab2, and so should be in your output.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is not clear. What language are you coding in? What do "->" & "as there is a relation between" mean? Do you use "relation" for FK? Relation(ship)s in the relational model are tables. FKs wrongly get called relation(ship)s. Constraints (FKs, PKs, etc) are not needed to query & if added cannot invalidate correct queries. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT F, S, E 
FROM Tab1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tab2 WHERE Tab1.F=Tab2.F AND Tab1.S=Tab2.S)
```

NOTE: If you also had info you wanted in Tab2 (you didn't specify but might) you could also join on both columns

```
SELECT Tab1.F, Tab1.S, Tab1.E --, Tab2.XXX
FROM Tab1 INNER JOIN Tab2 on Tab1.F=Tab2.F AND Tab1.S=Tab2.S
```

To validate this code, here is an example using temp tables

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Tab1 
FROM (VALUES ('F1','S1','R'), ('F1','S2','R2')
    , ('F1','S3','R1'), ('F2','S1','R2')
    , ('F2','S4','R4'), ('F1','S4','R')) as T1(F, S, E)

SELECT * 
INTO #Tab2
FROM (VALUES ('F1','S1','Val1'), ('F1','S3','Val2')
    , ('F2','S1','Val3'), ('F1','S4','Val4')) as T2(F, S, XXX)
SELECT * FROM #Tab1
SELECT * FROM #Tab2

SELECT F, S, E 
FROM #Tab1 as T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Tab2 as T2 WHERE T1.F=T2.F AND T1.S=T2.S)

SELECT T1.F, T1.S, T1.E, T2.XXX
FROM #Tab1 as T1 INNER JOIN #Tab2 as T2 on T1.F=T2.F AND T1.S=T2.S

DROP TABLE #Tab1 
DROP TABLE #Tab2
```

The results are identical except the second adds the dummy column I added to T2 for demonstration. The results are below. Note that the results table lists all and only the rows of T1 where the F & S values occur TOGETHER in T2.

```
F   S   E   XXX
F1  S1  R   Val1
F1  S3  R1  Val2
F2  S1  R2  Val3
F1  S4  R   Val4
```

As asked in the comments, a left (or right) outer join can use the same syntax, but would not satisfy the original request.

A Left Outer Join would include rows from T1 that had no corresponding {F,S} row in T2

A Right Outer Join would include (with all NULLs for the values of T1.F, T1.s, and T1.E) rows of T2 that had no corresponding {F,S} pairs in T1.

Both are perfectly valid queries that provide useful information, but not what was originally asked.

Comment: Thants great Robert Sheahan , thank you for looking into this

Comment: can this be executed with left semi join as well. The second query which you have provided does not return correct result.

Comment: Glad I could help, SO has saved me many hours and I'm happy to pay it forward :-) I tested the output and it appears identical for both queries, could you elaborate on how it is in error? Please state which output row was missing or extra, and I'll try to take a look later today. If you need to add rows to either of your original tables to illustrate the error, please clearly indicate which are new to save me the effort of a line by line comparison.